Switch virtual desktop on Win11 on an old keyboard without a windows key?
This is my taskbar. How do you switch desktops without a windows key?

Is there a way to set a keyboard shortcut for it myself?

I'm amazed by the fact that you have a keyboard without a windows key. All keyboards from the last 20+ years all have a windows key or other super key. Are you sure your keyboard does not have a windows key? Even an apple keyboard, which has a mac key, will work.

I have an IBM Model M, and my spare USB keyboard has just died in a coffee-related incident.

I see... I do think you'll gonna need a new keyboard then.

Well, yes and no. I'd forgotten how fantastic this old mechanical keyboard feels (it's been in storage for 25+ years).. so I just have to learn how to windows without a windows key

I think you can use Powertoys to reassign some other key that you don't use very often. This article specifically mentions the Model M, and suggests the right Alt key because it is easy to use for one-handed Windows shortcuts and most people use the left Alt key more frequently. You could also choose another seldom-used key, such as Scroll Lock or right Ctrl instead.

@MichaelHarvey that sounds like an excellent answer. Why don't you write one up? I'd be happy to vote it up.

@LPChip - answer added.

You can use the Keyboard Manager in Microsoft Powertoys to reassign some other key that you don't use very often.
This How-to Geek article 'How to Create a Windows Key If You Don't Have One' specifically mentions the Model M keyboard as one example of a keyboard without a Windows key, and suggests the right Alt key because it is easy to use for one-handed Windows shortcuts and most people use the left Alt key more frequently. You could also choose another seldom-used key, such as Scroll Lock or right Ctrl instead.
Personal note: I have just used Powertoys Keyboard Manager to reassign the right Ctrl key to be the same as the Windows key, and it works, both as a standalone key (brings up the Start Menu) and also as part of a two-key shortcut (works with I, D, etc). But Powertoys doesn't make it very intuitive, so follow the steps in the How-to Geek article carefully.
In particular this message caught me out, because it seems (to me) to suggest that the wanted key wasn't assigned, but it was really.

